# Setting child values as URL from JSON

Tags: python, json, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to send information (in this case, news articles) contained in a JSON file to Firebase, formatted like so:

```
{
"_type": "News",
"queryContext": {
    "originalQuery": "politics"
},
"readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/news/search?q=politics",
"totalEstimatedMatches": 31800,
"value": [
    {
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T19:53:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "The White House on Sunday brushed aside congressional Democrats\u2019 concerns about Atty. Gen. William Barr being handed extraordinary powers to declassify sensitive intelligence as part of a probe into the origins of the investigation into Russian efforts ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.AEA37BFFD9D0A9554FA9AEB2DFB82328&pid=News",
                "height": 393,
                "width": 700
            }
        },
        "name": "White House claims without proof that FBI has \u2018outrageous\u2019 corruption Barr will uncover",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "image": {
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_f6ee0777fa236afab60d094d1018c0b6&pid=news"
                    }
                },
                "name": "Los Angeles Times"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.latimes.com/politics/la-na-pol-trump-fbi-corruption-20190526-story.html"
    },
    {
        "about": [
            {
                "name": "Academy of the Canyons",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/033a8c1d-1559-b2a4-43d7-a19935bc5a57"
            },
            {
                "name": "Hope",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/e35840e7-6a9f-44a3-919e-19ee36c21103"
            }
        ],
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T19:40:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "Rep. Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez and other progressives criticized the New York Times on Sunday for writing that former White House aide Hope Hicks is facing an \"existential question\" over whether to comply with a congressional subpoena. Democrats on the ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.4BB68B63176AC7974EFE662AF950B9C3&pid=News",
                "height": 350,
                "width": 700
            }
        },
        "mentions": [
            {
                "name": "Academy of the Canyons"
            },
            {
                "name": "Hope"
            },
            {
                "name": "Business Insider"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez attacks former Trump aide Hope Hicks for 'considering participating in a coverup led by the President'",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "image": {
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_86ac6d5fd1859e509650fb5feef96bf7&pid=news"
                    }
                },
                "name": "Business Insider"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.businessinsider.com/aoc-hope-hicks-attacks-former-trump-aide-trump-coverup-2019-5"
    },
    {
        "about": [
            {
                "name": "Joe Biden",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/cad484f9-be75-7a78-12dd-16233f823cd7"
            },
            {
                "name": "Campaign",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/b83d549f-1d62-a989-a518-4fdc76be546e"
            },
            {
                "name": "Exposure",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/fd725e08-73c1-d154-546c-7c07d8a59ff1"
            }
        ],
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T20:03:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "Sen. Bernie Sanders (I-Vt.) plans to enjoy ice cream with New Hampshire voters to celebrate Memorial Day. He won\u2019t be far from former congressman John Delaney, another presidential candidate, who\u2019s in the midst of his 19th trip to the state and plans ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.D1E848B3E4536A1A8549F4102A3BEB82&pid=News",
                "height": 466,
                "width": 700
            }
        },
        "name": "Joe Biden\u2019s campaign of limited exposure: How long can he keep it up?",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "image": {
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_47a5d64fad0a365fb3b4d7af8c1361e7&pid=news"
                    }
                },
                "name": "The Washington Post"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/joe-bidens-campaign-of-limited-exposure-how-long-can-he-keep-it-up/2019/05/26/dcc045e4-7e2e-11e9-8bb7-0fc796cf2ec0_story.html"
    },
    {
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T20:01:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "Sen. Bernie Sanders, I-VT, has modestly misled or exaggerated some of his statements while campaigning for the 2020 Democratic nomination, according to a fact-checking report in the New York Times this weekend. Sanders, the longest-sitting Independent ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.0CA72069E1F8A492B7B9831C354BDB6E&pid=News",
                "height": 466,
                "width": 700
            }
        },
        "name": "New York Times Fact-Checks Bernie Sanders On Campaign Trail",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "image": {
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_9f6a911c9d042b01c6b85e9c12aa8647&pid=news"
                    }
                },
                "name": "International Business Times"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.ibtimes.com/new-york-times-fact-checks-bernie-sanders-campaign-trail-2795072"
    },
    {
        "about": [
            {
                "name": "Raid",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/d2fb9c28-3dad-6f78-2902-d1e0b94762e1"
            }
        ],
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T19:50:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "The San Francisco Police Officers Association on Saturday called for Police Chief Bill Scott to resign over the raid of a freelance journalist's home and office. \"It is time for Chief Scott to go.",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.58ABE32D6ABFD66302CF371380D901C2&pid=News",
                "height": 360,
                "width": 640
            }
        },
        "mentions": [
            {
                "name": "Raid"
            },
            {
                "name": "Union type"
            },
            {
                "name": "San Francisco Police Department"
            }
        ],
        "name": "San Francisco police union calls on chief to resign over journalist raid",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "image": {
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_fbfe507a57f598418fd179b0dec78111&pid=news"
                    }
                },
                "name": "The Hill"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://thehill.com/homenews/state-watch/445615-san-francisco-police-union-calls-on-chief-to-resign-over-journalist-raid"
    },
    {
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T19:12:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "This week on \"FOX News Sunday,\" Senate Judiciary Chairman Lindsey Graham said he strongly supported President Trump's decision to authorize the attorney general to declassify information related to the Russia investigation and he is disappointed that the ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.87AA2090AEE6F7A8E0305C058B6F37B7&pid=News",
                "height": 375,
                "width": 500
            }
        },
        "name": "Lindsey Graham: Not One Democrat Cares If FISA Court Was Defrauded By FBI And DOJ",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "name": "RealClearPolitics"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.realclearpolitics.com/video/2019/05/26/lindsey_graham_not_one_democrat_cares_if_fisa_court_was_defrauded_by_fbi_and_doj.html"
    },
    {
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T19:24:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "It seems nothing is too anti-Semitic for today\u2019s Democrats (\u201cDemocrats shoot down effort to rein in anti-Israel BDS movement,\u201d Web, May 23). The purpose of the Boycott, Divestment and Sanctions (BDS) movement is the elimination of Israel. BDS ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.805F4DD8F828E73C6D851B2797941ADB&pid=News",
                "height": 200,
                "width": 300
            }
        },
        "name": "LETTERS TO THE EDITOR: Jew-hater or weak, result same",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "image": {
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_104a9402f29a6a488f404306f122ddec&pid=news"
                    }
                },
                "name": "The Washington Times"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2019/may/26/letters-to-the-editor-jew-hater-or-weak-result-sam/"
    },
    {
        "about": [
            {
                "name": "Nancy Pelosi",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/707086df-b7b0-a823-28d8-79914cbfbd4e"
            },
            {
                "name": "Donald Trump",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/1a466af2-ed23-25bd-794d-1ca925e4681b"
            }
        ],
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T19:40:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "A Republican lawmaker said Sunday that he is concerned about President Trump\u2019s sharing of a heavily edited video that spliced together several verbal pauses by House Speaker Nancy Pelosi (D-Calif.). Rep. Will Hurd (R-Tex.) said that by sharing the video ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.2A6AB9FEB5A2F6110247FD7A8962F210&pid=News",
                "height": 466,
                "width": 700
            }
        },
        "name": "Republican lawmaker criticizes Trump for sharing heavily edited video of Pelosi",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "image": {
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_47a5d64fad0a365fb3b4d7af8c1361e7&pid=news"
                    }
                },
                "name": "The Washington Post"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/republican-lawmaker-criticizes-trump-for-sharing-heavily-edited-video-of-pelosi/2019/05/26/6e8b310e-7fde-11e9-933d-7501070ee669_story.html"
    },
    {
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T19:13:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "Harvard Law Professor Laurence Tribe told MSNBC's Joy Ann Reid Saturday morning on \"AM Joy\" that House Speaker Nancy Pelosi is right when she calls for an \"intervention\" against President Trump, but \"the most important kind of intervention is not a little ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.80B21F562977304C931AFB246B84696A&pid=News",
                "height": 375,
                "width": 500
            }
        },
        "name": "Laurence Tribe to Nancy Pelosi: The Most Important Kind Of \"Intervention\" Is An Impeachment Inquiry",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "name": "RealClearPolitics"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.realclearpolitics.com/video/2019/05/26/laurence_tribe_to_nancy_pelosi_the_most_important_kind_of_intervention_is_an_impeachment_inquiry.html"
    },
    {
        "about": [
            {
                "name": "Lindsey Graham",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/9ba65851-7a4a-18c2-c979-0daf5d69d46b"
            },
            {
                "name": "Chris Wallace",
                "readLink": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/entities/47e2deef-f6db-38b8-64fc-4ede147de399"
            }
        ],
        "category": "Politics",
        "datePublished": "2019-05-26T19:45:00.0000000Z",
        "description": "Trump's Point Man on China Trade Still Trying to Close the Deal Fox News Host Chris Wallace on Sunday challenged Sen. Lindsey Graham over the South Carolina Republican's past comments on ignoring subpoenas being grounds for impeachment. \"You call all of ...",
        "image": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.554F80686BD1C7DEF8D112F3FB3384B6&pid=News",
                "height": 315,
                "width": 600
            }
        },
        "mentions": [
            {
                "name": "Lindsey Graham"
            },
            {
                "name": "Chris Wallace"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fox News Channel"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Fox's Chris Wallace challenges Graham over past comments on ignoring subpoenas",
        "provider": [
            {
                "_type": "Organization",
                "image": {
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "contentUrl": "https://www.bing.com/th?id=AR_fbfe507a57f598418fd179b0dec78111&pid=news"
                    }
                },
                "name": "The Hill on MSN.com"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/foxs-chris-wallace-challenges-graham-over-past-comments-on-ignoring-subpoenas/ar-AABWiQt"
    }
]
```

While I've been able to send the JSON data to Firebase, the child values are numbered from 0-9 (my JSON has 10 news articles). 
[Here's the JSON output in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpFib.png)

The JSON file updates every 15 minutes with the latest news, which replaces the contents in this JSON (it only contains the 10 latest articles). Whenever I send the latest JSON to Firebase, it replaces the previous 0-9 values when instead I want to add more articles.

In order to prevent these values from being replaced, **I would like to set the child values as the "url" from that article in the JSON. Instead of showing up as 0,1,2,3 etc., it would list as its corresponding  article url**.

Here's my code for uploading the JSON to Firebase:

```
with open ('/var/www/mywebsite.com/html/private/scripts/data.json') as data_file:
    data=json.load(data_file)
    jsondata = json.dumps('/var/www/mywebsite.com/html/private/scripts/data.json')

cred = credentials.Certificate('/var/www/mywebsite.com/html/private/scripts/firebase-adminsdk.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://myapp.firebaseio.com/'
})

ref = db.reference('Feed')
ref.set(data)
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm relatively new to Python and  Firebase, pardon my inexperience in phrasing some of this question.